Turn HTTP Server into an HTTPS server in Qt 6.8.0
Apologies for this being basic - I've inherited code, and I don't entirely understand all the complexities. Will try to provide extra information if I can!
I previously had a server being set up within one of my classes using Qt 6.7.3:
_http = make_unique<QHttpServer>();
QSslConfiguration ssl_config;
ssl_config.setProtocol(QSsl::SslProtocol::TlsV1_3);
ssl_config.setCiphers("TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");
ssl_config.setLocalCertificate(<tls_cert>);
ssl_config.setPrivateKey(<tls_key>);
_http->sslSetup(ssl_config);

However, sslSetup has been cleaned out in the upgrade to 6.8.0, with no simple instructions for dummies such as myself as to how to replace it.

Refer to the simple HTTP server example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthttpserver-simple-example.html.  In short, you need to call bind on the QHttpServer with a QSslServer instance.
